# valueForKeyPath sum doesn't return correct value

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing a method in a class that returns the sum of all the elements of `grades`, a (private instance) NSMutableArray of NSDecimalNumbers

```
grades = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I receive a string formatted like "(length) - (value) (value) ..."
( Example: `"3 - 90.5 85.2 89.6"` )
This is how I fill the array

```
-(void) setGrades: (NSString *) list{
     NSArray *arr = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

     int i = 2; //start from 2 to ignore length and '-'
     for (; i<[arr count]; i++)
     {
         NSString *temp = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
         [grades addObject: [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: temp]];
     }
}
```

The sum method

```
-(double) getSum{
     double sum = [[grades valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.doubleValue"]doubleValue];
     return sum;
}
```

returns something completely incorrect. For example, with the above example data it returns `0`. Or if i remove the last value (so it would be `"2 - 90.5 85.2"`) it returns `-1717986918`. Is the error in the way I fill the array or something else? How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that `grades` is empty before you start adding objects to it?

Comment: Yes, I checked to make sure it is empty before adding objects, it returns 0 still.

Comment: Why are you converting them using `NSDecimalNumber`, use `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[temp integerValue]]` and another problem with your value is, it considers `-` as value while you split them using space.

Comment: I need them as decimals not integers, is there something wrong with `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: Can you try logging the actual values using `NSLog(@"Grades: %@", grades)`?

Comment: Yes, the actual values match the input. It seems that there is something wrong in type conversion, because I get the correct values when I return it as `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Why are you using NSDecimalNumber if you're going to convert to double?

Answer (score 1):

in this method of yours

```
-(void) setGrades: (NSString *) list{
 NSArray *arr = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

 int i = 2; //start from 2 to ignore length and '-'
 for (; i<[arr count]; i++)
 {
     NSString *temp = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
     [grades addObject: [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: temp]];
 }
```

}

Don't convert it into NSDecimalNumber and add it in string format to array. And make sure you had allocated memory to grades array.

```
grades = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then later in this method

```
    -(double) getSum{
     double sum = [[grades valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.doubleValue"]doubleValue];
     return sum;
}
```

do something like this:

```
-(double) getSum{

double sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< grades.count; i++){
    sum += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[grades objectAtIndex:i]]doubleValue];
}
return sum;
```

}

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Better choose one type and stick with it.

NSDecimal:

```
[grades addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: temp]];

NSDecimalNumber *sum = [grades valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

double:

```
[grades addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[temp doubleValue]]];

double sum = [[grades valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"] doubleValue];
```

NSString:

```
[grades addObject:temp];

NSString *sum = [grades valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```